# Referencing CSS and JS file in Github Pages?

Tags: javascript, css, github, web, hosting

Recently I have been trying to make a website.

I make all the content locally and push it to github pages, i already change the path of all the images and CSS and JS to the repository. all the image are working fine but my HTML file wont connect to the CSS and JS files.

I did a bit of research and found out that we can use rawgit.com as a CDN, but it does not work for me. I know it should be possible since i saw some people using github pages and have their css working fine, i just cant get it to work. Here is my repo and index.

```
https://github.com/andygiovanny/andygiovanny.github.io
https://github.com/andygiovanny/andygiovanny.github.io/blob/master/index.html
```

Here is on my local files [Local Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx0GQ.png) and here is on github [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtJII.png)

I am quite new at this and hoping to get help, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best in this instance to use [relative urls](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html) for your static files hosted on your own site, so for example change:

```
<link href="andygiovanny.github.io/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to simply:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This way it will load for you in whatever environment you are working in. I use something called [middleman](https://middlemanapp.com/) for building my website on GitHub pages and they do the same thing as can be seen in my [repo](https://github.com/peter-featherstone/peter-featherstone.github.io).

This is the same for the links inside your CSS files too, for example you are referencing your images as below:

```
.mainContent{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url('andygiovanny.github.io/IMAGE FILE/Background.svg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

But it needs to be like:

```
.mainContent{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url('/IMAGE FILE/Background.svg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

As a side note, it is advisable not to have spaces in your file locations and by convention they should be lowercased, with hyphens replacing spaces, I would rename `IMAGE FILE` to `image-file`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I edit it, but unfortunately, it still does not read the javascript and css. I am quite confused also on what is wrong.

Comment: I just found your site at https://andygiovanny.github.io/ and the CSS is loading fine for me...

Comment: I don't know why it is not working for me, let me attach a screenshot of it on my post (updated, seems like the CSS and JS not working) for me at least

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an issue that the images inside the CSS you are trying to load aren't loading not an issue with the CSS itself? For example https://andygiovanny.github.io/css/andygiovanny.github.io/IMAGE FILE/Background.svg is not a valid URL

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect the fact that it is actually your images causing the issues.

Comment: I actually already change all the image file to the github repo links, for example here is link for the tomato andygiovanny.github.io/IMAGE FILE/Chill Tomato.svg and the image actually appear, but this image is the one that i link directly from HTML file. the background image from CSS is not yet recognized by it

Comment: Yes but in your CSS you are not referencing them correctly. Also, don't have spaces in your file names.

Comment: Hmm well, the image working properly in HTML. But I think the HTML won't read the CSS file as a stylesheet. Because it is not an only image problem (background image styled in css) but the margin, font and padding is also missing. So shouldn't it be problem on referencing the css?

Comment: I can see images are not be loaded in your CSS. Run your site with your network tab open and you will see all the 404 errors. Your CSS is loading fine...

Comment: Also as the other poster mentioned above, you are mixing your content of http with https. Update your external files to the https protocol and internal to relative. The combination of their answer and mine should fix all your problems...

Comment: hey thanks, let me try tweaking stuff for a few hours. Thanks for your time

Comment: No problem, it shouldn't take more than 5 minutes to complete. You just need to add a couple of s's to your external files and remove any domain references from your internal files. If you get it working, it would be nice to give an upvote to me and the other poster and accept an answer. Have a great day :-)

Comment: Hey! I remove the domain reference and it worked like a charm, some of my Javascripts still not working though. Maybe it's the external protocol problem

Answer (score 2):

You must include the scripts and stylesheets over the HTTPS protocol. Just look at the console. Or you can download the stylesheets and scripts and move to your folder. So you can include from project folders.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- Like this! -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving a nextjs app on github pages then you have to add an empty `.nojekyll` next to the `_next` folder (generated by `next export`), otherwise github pages will ignore that folder resulting in 404 for the .js and .css files inside that directory...

Source: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/3335